# How to check checkbox when label is clicked

Tags: html

Lets say I have a checkbox control and a label.

what I want to do is when I click on label then checkbox should get checked.

How do we do that? I know its a pure html problem. I have seen this in say (gmail, facebook)

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Cgm/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `for` attribute to your label and the same `id` to the checkbox - http://jsfiddle.net/k8Cgm/2/

```
<label for="chk">I am a checkbox</label>
<input name="chk" id="chk" type="checkbox" value="some" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You must set an `id` for your checkbox, then refer it in the `for` attribute of the label.

```
<input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="some" />
<label for="chk">I am a checkbox</label>
```

Comment: You can also put the input inside the label `<label>Click me! <input type='checkbox' /></label>

Comment: The id you use must be unique within your html document - basic but often missed!

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the for argument to the label and an id to your input-tag.

See your example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ3Zc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer the label to a input without the id, and also without adding what to refer. You have to add the id to the input and the referrer in the label. You can see the update example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8Cgm/3/

---

For more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp